# How to compare variables and return common variables in R

Tags: r, compare

I have a very simple dataset, with one column for ID numbers and one column for DOB of that individual.

Example:

```
x_df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          ID = c("ID-1", "ID-2", "ID-2", "ID-3", "ID-4", "ID-5"),
         DOB = c("4/16/1955", "9/4/1976", "9/4/1976", "4/16/1955", "2/10/1995",
                 "11/29/1980")
)
```

I am trying to write a code in R that will compare all the DOBs and print the IDs and DOBs when the DOB is the same but the ID is different.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

lets arrange the data by DOBs, pairs can be compared

```
library(tidyverse)

x_df %>% 
  group_by(DOB) %>% 
  mutate(idord = paste0("x", 1:n()) ) %>% 
  spread(idord, ID) %>% 
  filter(x1 != x2)
```

result is

```
  DOB       x1    x2   
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 4/16/1955 ID-1  ID-3
```

if you might have more than 2 pairs then you can use this

```
x_df %>% 
  group_by(DOB) %>% 
  summarise(idcount = n_distinct(ID), IDall = paste(ID, collapse = "|")) %>% 
  filter(idcount > 1)
```

number of IDs and all IDs in one cell

```
  DOB       idcount IDall    
  <chr>       <int> <chr>    
1 4/16/1955       2 ID-1|ID-3
```